# Estimate an element's height before element styling is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a good way to calculate/estimate an element's height while the the element is not being displayed or has not been rendered?

I'm looking for more dynamic-rendering-friendly alternatives to using node.offsetHeight. This is particularly in cases where the element's styling has just been added via javascript and the browser hasn't yet caught on the the change.

Comment: How accurate do you want it to be?

Comment: Hmmm, well I imagined it couldn't be perfect, but if it could consistently be within ~10% of the actual number that would probably still be useful.

Comment: Perfect’s the easiest way to do it, but apparently you need speed, so… what sort of restrictions can you put on the element being measured? Things like `position: absolute; left: 10px; right: 1rem;` can make a horrible tree of layout dependencies that you’d be hard-pressed to figure out faster than the browser.

Comment: I think if you use jQuery's `.height()` method on a hidden element, it temporarily shows the element, gets its height, and then hides it again.